# extract specific lines out of file (PYTHON)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

i have a big problems in extracting lines out of a text file: 
My text file ist built like the following:

```
BO_ 560 VR_Sgn_1: ALMN
  SG_1_ Vr
  SG_2_ Vr_set
  SG_3 Dars
BO _ 561 VSet_Current : ACM
  SG_2_ Vr_set
  SG_3 Dars
BO_ 4321 CDSet_tr : APL
  SG_1_ Vr
  SG_2_ Vr_set
  SG_3 Dars
  SG_1_ Vr_1
  SG_2_ Vr_set
  SG_3 Dars
```

....

The textfile includes about 1000 of these "BO_ " Blocks...

i would like to have the expressions between the "BO_ "s.
Here my previous code:

```
show_line= False
with open("test.txt") as f:
   for line in f:
     if line.startswith("BO_ 560"):
       show_line=True
     elif line.startswith("\n")
       show_line= False
     if show_line and not line.startswith("BO_ 560")
       print line
```

in this case i would like to expect the following output:

```
     SG_1_ Vr
     SG_2_ Vr_set
     SG_3 Dars
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I am not sure I understand, you want all of the lines that does NOT start with BO? or do you want to provide a <Number> and get all of the lines after BO_ <Number> down until the next BO_?


also what is the output you are receiving now?

Comment: Does your code work? What does it do wrong if it doesn't work?

Comment: i got frames, that begin with  "BO_ #NUMBER" . In the prior example above i delivered the algorithm the string "BO_ 560" and expect the following output:

`         SG_1_ Vr
          SG_2_ Vr_set
         SG_3 Dars`

my algorithm alway gives me this:
`       SG_1_ Vr
        SG_2_ Vr_set
        SG_3 Dars
   BO _ 561 VSet_Current : ACM
      SG_2_ Vr_set
      SG_3 Dars
  BO_ 4321 CDSet_tr : APL
      SG_1_ Vr
     SG_2_ Vr_set
     SG_3 Dars
     SG_1_ Vr_1
     SG_2_ Vr_set
     SG_3 Dars`

....but thats too much . I only want to have the expression between the "BO_ "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's problem with:

```
elif line.startswith("\n")
```

You want to wait for next "BO_" instead of EOL to disable show_line, try this:

```
show_line = False
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("BO_ 560"):
            show_line = True
        elif line.startswith("BO_"):
            show_line = False
        elif show_line:
            print line
```

Comment: Do you know how i can differentiate between "BO_ 48" and "BO_ 480" with the code you gave me ?

Comment: the easiest way is to add space to the end of the string ie: `if line.startswith("BO_ 48 ")`

Answer (score 0):

You need to skip further processing of the line when you see `BO_ or BO _`

I am not sure if you only want for first block or all.

Does below option solve your problem.

```
show_line = False
    with open("test.txt") as f:
        for line in f:
            line  = line.strip("\n")
            if line.startswith("BO_ ") or line.startswith("BO _ "):
                show_line = False if show_line else True
                continue
            if show_line:
                print line
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is to output all the blocks between "BO's" you can do something like this:

```
with open("test.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("BO"):
            print ""
        else:
            print line
```

Comment: no, i would like to give the algorithm a string ... for example : "BO_ 560". The algorithm should give me the sentences after that .beginning with "SG_" .... But only the expressions until the next "BO_ "...